Plot constant x and y lines from data from a table
I want to extract values from a table and plot a constant x line and a constant y line given the values. I've managed to do that with the y value but for some reason I get an error for the x line.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

% Define the table
\pgfplotstableread{
x   y
1   2
3   4
5   6
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

    % Access the first row of column "x" by name
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of\mytable
    \let\firstrowx=\pgfplotsretval

    % Access the first row of column "y" by name
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{y}\of\mytable
    \let\firstrowy=\pgfplotsretval

    \addplot {x^2};
    \addplot[domain=-4:4] {\firstrowy};
    \addplot coordinates {(\firstrowx, 0), (\firstrowx, 30)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


The \addplot coordinates reads a sequence of point coordinates without separator. Example, taken from the pgfplots manual, section 4.3.1, Coordinate Lists:
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
(0,0)
(0.5,1)
(1,2)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

So, simply remove the comma
\addplot coordinates {(\firstrowx, 0) (\firstrowx, 30)};

Full example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

% Define the table
\pgfplotstableread{
x   y
1   2
3   4
5   6
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

    % Access the first row of column "x" by name
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of\mytable
    \let\firstrowx=\pgfplotsretval

    % Access the first row of column "y" by name
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{y}\of\mytable
    \let\firstrowy=\pgfplotsretval

    \addplot {x^2};
    \addplot[domain=-4:4] {\firstrowy};
    \addplot coordinates {(\firstrowx, 0) (\firstrowx, 30)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



If only the error messages were actually helpful...
thanks so much for your answer!
